# Delete duplicate records only on condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete duplicates for example I want to delete this row "Test2, 321, 0" because there is a duplicate, but in row 1 and 2 I only want to delete row two because the type id is higher then the current duplicate in row one.

This is my table

```
ID, Name, RecordNum, Type
--------------------------
1, Test, 123, 0
2, Test, 123, 1
3, Test2, 321, 0
4, Test2, 321, 0
```

I can delete duplicate in row 4 using this query. but I cannot seem to figure out how to delete row 2 because row 1 is the same but type number is lower. and if the type number is 2 it wins and you have to delete any duplicates with 0 and 1 type numbers that have the same name and recordnum.

```
WITH dup2 as ( 
  SELECT Name
       , RecordNum
       , Type ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name, RecordNum, Type ORDER BY ID ASC) AS NumOfDups 
    FROM MyTbale) 
  delete FROM dup2 WHERE NumOfDups > 1
```

Comment: I assume your query, as stated, has been copied incorrectly?

Comment: Do you want to delete row 2 and row 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically you want to keep only one record for each `Name, RecordNum` group.  If the Type is the same keep only the lowest ID, if the Type is different keep the lowest type:

```
WITH dup2 AS 
( 
         SELECT  NAME, 
                 RecordNum, 
                 NumOfDups = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(
                                 PARTITION BY NAME, RecordNum 
                                 ORDER BY CASE WHEN Type=2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Type, Id)
         FROM    MyTbale) 
DELETE 
FROM   dup2 
WHERE  NumOfDups > 1
```

[<kbd>**SQL-Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4355/1/0)

**Edited** according to comment: *"Let say when the type = 2 then I want to delete the other matching records that have a zero or one for type, so two wins here."*

Comment: hi work perfectly except for one think I missed, sorry late night. Let say when the type = 2 then I want to delete the other matching records that have a zero or one for type, so two wins here.

Comment: @Etienne: then use `CASE`. I've edited the answer and the fiddle.