# SQL Server dedupe with priority

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a table called transactions that looks like this:

```
    name    status
------------------------
    harry   available
    harry   expired
    harry   cancelled
    barry   available
    sally   expired
    sally   available
    jane    available
    jane    used
    nelly   available
```

I want to delete rows in the table with priority placed on those that are 'expired', 'cancelled' or 'used' over 'available.' So, if I dedupe the table it would look like this:

```
    name    status
-------------------------
    harry   expired
    harry   cancelled
    barry   available
    sally   expired
    jane    used
    nelly   available
```

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I've tried creating two tables and then joining them like so:

```
/****** remove available ******/
WITH CTE AS(SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[status]
      ,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [id]
      ,[name])
  FROM [transactions])
  DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1 AND [status] not in('used','cancelled','expired')

/****** available only  ******/
WITH CTE AS(SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[status]
      ,RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [id]
      ,[name])
  FROM [transactions_2])
  DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1 AND [status] not in('used','cancelled','expired')
```

Then I would union [transactions] & [transactions_2], but that didn't work...

Comment: what do you mean by "dedupe"? Do you mean you want to `DELETE` the rows that aren't in your second list, or that you want a `SELECT` statement that only returns those rows?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49861689/edit) your question with your attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete duplicate records only on condition in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474241/delete-duplicate-records-only-on-condition-in-sql-server)

Comment: Ummmm.....you have no duplicates in your sample data. Your question and rules are just too vague here.

Comment: Yes by dedupe I mean delete the rows. I've edited my question to include what I've tried so far.

Comment: This site is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it in two steps.

1. Delete "duplicates" where the status and name are the same
2. Delete "available" records where any records with other status exist

`delete from transactions t1
where exists (select 1
              from transactions t2
              where t2.name = t1.name 
              and   t2.status = t1.status
              and t2.id > t1.id)`



`delete from transactions t1
where t1.status = 'available'
and exists (select 1
            from transactions t2
            where t2.name = t1.name 
            and t2.status in ( 'expired', 'cancelled' , 'used') )`

Answer (score 1):

with window function
this is the select - not the delete

```
declare @T table (name varchar(10), avail varchar(10));
insert into @T values 
    ('harry', 'available')
  , ('harry', 'expired')
  , ('harry', 'cancelled')
  , ('barry', 'available')
  , ('sally', 'expired')
  , ('sally', 'available')
  , ('jane', 'available')
  , ('jane', 'used')
  , ('nelly', 'vailable');

select * 
from ( select * 
            , count(*) over (partition by t.name) as cnt
       from @T t
     ) tt
where tt.avail in ('expired', 'cancelled', 'used')
   or tt.cnt = 1 
order by tt.name, tt.avail;
```

delete

```
delete tt
from ( select * 
            , count(*) over (partition by t.name) as cnt
       from @T t
     ) tt
where tt.avail not in ('expired', 'cancelled', 'used')
  and tt.cnt > 1;

select * 
from @T 
order by name, avail;
```